# Как узнать имя селектора после события в jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть некий набор элементов, по которым обрабатывается нажатие. Как вернуть именно тот селектор, по которому jQuery отловил нажатие?

```
$( "#element, .element1, .element2, ..., .elementN" ).click(function(event) {
     // Вернуть ИМЯ: element1 или element2 и тп
});
```

Comment: вам нужно получить именно  `#element` или `.element1`, а не сам объект, чтобы с ним манипулировать?

Comment: Мне нужно получить ИМЯ селектора, чтобы понять, что именно из набора было нажато (либо класс "element1", либо, если отловлено по ID#, то "element").

Answer (score 1):

Если вернуть атрибут `name`, то
`this.name` или `$(this).attr("name")`

Объект будет `this` или `$(this)`

Comment: Сообщение было опубликовано в качестве ответа, но оно не содержит ответа на вопрос.

Comment: Вопрос был отредактирован, первоначально звучал как:  Вернуть ИМЯ элемента по которому кликнули

Comment: Вы же в курсе что тут можно посмотреть [историю редактирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/876837/revisions)? И согласно ней были только изменены отступы.

Comment: В комментарии написано: `// Вернуть ИМЯ: element1 или element2 и тп`.

Comment: Ниже в комментарии автора: Мне нужно получить ИМЯ селектора

Comment: И это имя класса либо id, а не атрибут `name` объекта.

Answer (score 1):

Если не находи по id то ищет по классу в classList, возвращает первый подходящий класс. Если один элемент имеет два класса указанных в `selector`, то возвращается первый совпавший. id всегда первый в приоритете.

```js
const selector = "#element, .element1, .element2"

$(selector).click(function (event) {
  const myClass = [...this.classList].find(i => selector.includes('.' + i))

  console.log(this.id || myClass)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element">element</div>
<div class="element1 fff">element1 fff</div>
<div class="bbb element2 rrr">bbb element2 rrr</div>
<div class="element1 element2">element1+element2</div>
```

Comment: а если класс будет `element2 one two three` ?

Comment: teran именно, классов может быть много.

Comment: про это не указано в условии, если надо возвращать первый класс то `this.classList[0]`

Comment: нужно вернуть именно то, по чему было отловлено

Comment: понял, исправил

Comment: да! большое спасибо!

Comment: У [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) есть метод contains

Comment: В общем, `selectorArr.filter(s=>s[0]==='.').map(s=>s.slice(1)).find(s=>this.classList.contains(s))` =)

Comment: сделал по другому

Comment: можно еще `this.className.includes(i.slice(1))` вместо `classList`, не знаю как лучше будет

Comment: Я понял что точка не нужна, можете опять ставить как ответ. Сильно укоротил код.

Answer (score -1):

```
$( "#element, .element1, .element2, .elementN").click(function(event) {
       console.log(e.target.id || e.target.className);
});
```

Comment: Если произойдет клик на 1 элемент, что вернет ваш код?

Comment: Название id или класса, по которому произошел клик

Comment: "а если класс будет `element2 one two three` ? – teran 19 минут назад"